# Problems with external .so libaries in nuget package

Tags: c#, linux, nuget, external, .so

I've got a nuget package which contains some libraries (.dll and .so).
We need the .dll for our windows environment and the .so for the Linux environment.
I checked if both files are packed in the nuget and this is the case.

If I install this nuget into a webservice and start it, the .dll gets placed in the correct place (the executable path). However the .so files does not get copied, even if the webservice is started in the Linux environment. If this is the case the .dll is also copied into the executable path.

This is how I import the files inside the nuget project:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\..\Lib\win64\dll\ericapi.dll">
        <Link>ericapi.dll</Link>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>        
    <Content Include="..\..\Lib\lin64\lib\libericapi.so">
        <Link>libericapi.so</Link>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

this is a screenshot of the lib directory of my nuget:
[image]

If the Webservice is started locally only the .dll gets copied into "bin\Debug\net8.0"

Why is this the case. Can only .dll files be copied this way?

Comment: What is the target frame work?  Do you have same version of Net 8.0 installed (or runtime version)?  Did you compile library on Windows?  Did you do a clean build?

Comment: The target framework is .NET8.0 and i also got the same version installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i just got it solved. I replaced "PackagePath" with "PackageCopyToOutput". With this setup i´ve got all the files in the right direcotry, even on Linux:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\..\Lib\win64\dll\ericapi.dll">
        <Link>ericapi.dll</Link>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
        <Pack>true</Pack>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>        
    <Content Include="..\..\Lib\lin64\lib\libericapi.so">
        <Link>libericapi.so</Link>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
        <Pack>true</Pack>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: you might also want to use `PackagePath` - I have one that uses, for example: `<PackagePath>runtimes/linux-x64/native/mylibraryname.so</PackagePath>` - it should really be in the correct package location